# /usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip Error on or near line 85; exiting with status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, intel

```
 (ankit) ankit@ankit-HP-Notebook:~/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.3.343/deployment_tools/demo/ $./demo_squeezenet_download_convert_run.sh

 ################################################### Downloading the Caffe model and the prototxt Installing dependencies Run sudo -E apt

 -y install build-essential python3-pip virtualenv cmake libpng12-dev libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev

 libswscale-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libgstreamer1.0-0

 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base Hit:1

 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease Hit:2

 http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease                         

 Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading

 state information... Done 1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list

 --upgradable' to see it. Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done

 build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).

 libcairo2-dev is already the newest version (1.14.6-1).

 libpango1.0-dev is already the newest version (1.38.1-1). cmake is

 already the newest version (3.5.1-1ubuntu3). gstreamer1.0-plugins-base

 is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2). libglib2.0-dev is

 already the newest version (2.48.2-0ubuntu4). libgstreamer1.0-0 is

 already the newest version (1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1). libgtk2.0-dev is

 already the newest version (2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2). libpng12-dev is

 already the newest version (1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1). libavcodec-dev is

 already the newest version (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).

 libavformat-dev is already the newest version

 (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1). libswscale-dev is already the newest

 version (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1). python3-pip is already the newest

 version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4). virtualenv is already the newest version

 (15.0.1+ds-3ubuntu1). The following packages were automatically

 installed and are no longer required:   linux-headers-4.15.0-29

 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic   linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic

 linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic  

 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to

 remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not

 upgraded. The directory '/home/ankit/.cache/pip/http' or its parent

 directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been

 disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If

 executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. The directory

 '/home/ankit/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the

 current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the

 permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo,

 you may want sudo's -H flag. Requirement already satisfied (use

 --upgrade to upgrade): pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages 
Requirement already satisfied

 (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

 You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 18.0 is available.

 You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip'

 command. Run

 /home/ankit/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.3.343/deployment_tools/demo/..
/model_downloader/downloader.py

 --name "squeezenet1.1" --output_dir "/home/ankit/openvino_models"

 ###############|| Start downloading models ||############### ...100%, 9 KB, 15577 KB/s, 0 seconds passed ========= squeezenet1.1.prototxt

 ====> /home/ankit/openvino_models/classification/squeezenet/1.1/caffe/squeezenet1.1.prototxt

 ###############|| Start downloading weights ||############### ...100%, 4834 KB, 1842 KB/s, 2 seconds passed =========

 squeezenet1.1.caffemodel ====>

 /home/ankit/openvino_models/classification/squeezenet/1.1/caffe/squeezenet1.1.caffemodel

 ###############|| Start downloading topologies in tarballs ||###############

 ###############|| Post processing ||###############

 ========= Changing input dimensions in squeezenet1.1.prototxt =========

 ################################################### Configure Model Optimizer INTEL_CVSDK_DIR environment variable is not set. Trying to

 run ./setvars.sh to set it.  [setupvars.sh] OpenVINO environment

 initialized

 ################################################### Install Model Optimizer dependencies Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu

 xenial InRelease Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial

 InRelease                      Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com

 xenial InRelease                             Hit:4   

 Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease

 Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease


 Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading

 state information... Done 1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list

 --upgradable' to see it. Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done python3-venv

 is already the newest version (3.5.1-3). libgfortran3 is already the

 newest version (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10). python3-pip is already the

 newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4). The following packages were

 automatically installed and are no longer required:  


 linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic  

 linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic  

 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to

 remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not

 upgraded. /usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip Error on or near

 line 85; exiting with status 1 (ankit)
```

Comment: Please format your code as code by indenting it with a tab

Answer (score 1):

run the setupvars.sh script:

```
source /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk/bin/setupvars.sh
```

Also, try to run the squeezenet demo with root privilages:

```
sudo su
./demo_squeezenet_download_convert_run.sh
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: and i trying to solve this error i got one more error which i have posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051994/failed-to-fetch-https-download-docker-com-linux-ubuntu-dists-dists-xenial-stab  so can you help me please me to solve both error ... thank you ...............